# Exponential to base 10

Tags: r, knitr

I came up with this UDF, there must be a better way?

If the number is `<0.00001` then use base 10 notation instead of `e-`. Input range is `0-1`.

**report.Rmd**

````
```{r temp}
udf_expTo10 <- function(x){

  x <- as.character(x)

  if(grepl("e-",x)){
    x <- round(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,"e-"))),1)
    x <- paste0(x[1]," x 10^-",x[2],"^")}else{
      x <- round(as.numeric(x),4)}

  return(as.character(x))
  }

```

pvalue = `r udf_expTo10(0.000000123)`

pvalue = `r udf_expTo10(0.00123)`

pvalue = `r udf_expTo10(1)`

pvlaue = `r udf_expTo10("-1.222123e-15")`
````

**report.docx**

[image]

Comment: It's not the point of your question but how can you get a negative pvalue?

Comment: @CathG I knew someone would point this out, like you said, `not the point of this question`. I was just testing different inputs.

Comment: well, as you indicated that the range is `0-1`, it already surprised me in the first "version" of the question but I thought why not, but it became even more surprising when calling it "pvalue" ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been done in **knitr** long time ago, you can simply write `` $`r -1.222123e-15`$ `` or `` $`r 0.000000123`$ ``. I'm not sure why you were trying to reinvent the wheel, but I'm open to suggestions to improve `knitr:::format_sci_one`.

Comment: Had a feeling it existed, Google didn't help... so reinvented my own wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposition with (multiple) `gsub`, it's different but I doubt you can say it's "a better way"...

```
expTo10_bis <- function(x) {

   # beginning is the same as yours
   x <- as.character(x)

   if(grepl("e-", x)){
        # now the gsub "parade":
        x <- gsub("e", " x 10^", gsub("(?<=e-)0", "", x, perl=T))
        x <- gsub("-*\\d\\.\\d+", round(as.numeric(gsub("([\\S]*)\\sx\\s10.*$", "\\1", x, perl=T)), 1), x, perl=T)

   } else { # end is same as yours
        x <- as.character(round(as.numeric(x), 4))
   }

   return(x)
}

expTo10_bis(0.0000023456) # "2.3 x 10^-6"
expTo10_bis(0.0123456) # "0.0123"
# and if you really want to test negative values:
expTo10_bis(-0.00000000000000000000000000789456) # "-7.9 x 10^-27"
```

Comment: Thought you might like to know, see Yihui's answer.